# How to upload leak traces of leakCanary to HipChat room

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

https://gist.github.com/pyricau/06c2c486d24f5f85f7f0#file-squaredebugapplication-java

I am trying to follow the code here to upload leak traces to HipChat room. I'm pretty sure I am using the valid auth token and room number, but nothing happens there. Also I did register the service and override the install() method with this specific service. Has anyone succeeded in doing that? Any advice is appreciable.

Comment: Now I am getting retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 Bad Request here

Comment: Have resolved this, because of too long request body.